# A set together with its subset

Tags: terminology

Are there any particular term for a pair $(U;A)$ where $U$ is a set and $A\in\mathscr{P}U$? That is, saying informally, $(U;A)$ is a set $A$ together with a set $U$ on which $A$ is defined ($A$ is defined as a subset of $U$).

Comment: One could consider this pair as the inclusion $A\subset U$...

Comment: How about *extension*? But I don't think there is a standard term for that. The closer I know of is [pointed set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set).

Comment: You could call it a structure with one unary relation, or simply a unary relation $A$ on $U$.

Answer (score 1):

For more general situations of this kind, there are indeed names.

For example, one can talk about filtration, if you have a *set* of sets with certain inclusion properties.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_%28abstract_algebra%29

If the sets are vector spaces, this is a (very trivial) flag.

But normally, one does not use this terminology for the simple situation of "a set and a subset". You can view it as an element of the inclusion relation, but there are few contexts where this would be helpful.